# Sudden Webkitformboundary error from my connection php file that is 4866 lines long

Tags: php, webkit, cpanel

I am trying to narrow down what the error is by eliminating code, but I have had 2 things come up that seems to be related.  When I try to upload my master database connection / function file to Control Panel via the ajax loader page I checked the box Yes to overwrite existing file, but when it tries to load this one file I get "File file xxxx you uploaded already exists".

Now when I go to any page that has file xxxx included on it I get the following error:

```
    <body style>
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryU3iel31fONLdFKZX
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="overwrite"

    0   ......
```

Anyone run into this issue before?  I'm currently tearing apart the file to find if someone inside this PHP file is causing the error for upload to Control Panel + the webkitformboundary error printing to the page direclty below the  tag.

Comment: It appears after reverting back to an old file and moving all the changes done identically there was no error in the code.  There must have been some corruption that happened to the file.  This can be closed now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears after reverting back to an old file and moving all the changes done identically there was no error in the code. There must have been some corruption that happened to the file I was editing with notepad++. This can be closed now.